# How can i show this in xml file ??Anyone there Who can show me the sample code of this xml?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

I wanna implement the XML file in my app, please anyone give me the pattern of this XML code??

I try it with table layout but it's not like is, Please anyone help me to give me the clear concept in details or sample code of this pattern

```
<TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="1">

            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:text="tumi"
                    android:padding="10dip" />
                <TextView
                    android:text="ami"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:padding="10dip" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:text="bal"
                    android:padding="10dip" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="falau"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:padding="10dip" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:text="bal"
                    android:padding="10dip" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="falau"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:padding="10dip" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:text="bal"
                    android:padding="10dip" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="falau"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:padding="10dip" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:text="bal"
                    android:padding="10dip" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="falau"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:padding="10dip" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:text="bal"
                    android:padding="10dip" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="falau"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:padding="10dip" />

            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnrH5.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9I6hy.png)

Here is the output of my XML file

Comment: This is what you to implement on your own.

Comment: looks like a `TableLayout`, or a `ListView` (`RecyclerView`). What exactly is a problem for you to design it?

Comment: I need the source code of this pattern

Comment: then write it. What stops you from writing it?

Comment: Did you event r to do this? It is not even hard to do this.

Comment: I tried it with table layout then it's not like as this

Comment: what was the result of what you tried?

Comment: I added my code and output ,sir

Comment: try this :https://android.jlelse.eu/easily-adding-nested-recycler-view-in-android-a7e9f7f04047,  https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Comment: add paddings, gravity, weights

Comment: Thanks a lot  Vladyslav Matviienko and Rahul Khatri

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adview"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="Name"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/blue" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:drawableBottom="@drawable/settings"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="Audio"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/blue" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:drawableBottom="@drawable/settings"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="Audio"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/blue" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="Audio"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/blue" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="Audio"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/blue" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="Audio"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/blue" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="Audio"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/blue" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="Audio"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/blue" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="Audio"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/blue" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<View
    android:id="@+id/adview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I hope this is useful to you